# Codenameone Connect to Google Drive

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, codenameone

This may be a dumb questions, but I haven't found an answer after lots of searching. I need to do two things, I need to allow my app to login to google, then save a file the users google drive.

I've found some steps on how to connect to google drive, but either its outdated or I don't have the correct libraries because it fails to compile:  https://www.codenameone.com/google-login.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the login part there are good instructions in [this blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-2.html)

Another sample of code to login to Google in [this demo](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/blob/master/SignIn/src/com/codename1/demos/signin/SignIn.java#L123-L152)

You'll need to set the scope of the OAuth2 login to the appropriate [Google Drive Scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth)

For saving files to drive, you should use `ConnectionRequest` to create the HTTP requests directly to their [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in). There's even an [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_31hJtWjlw) explaining the concept.

There's a quick [Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive) which enables your web site to allow users to save files to their Drive account from an arbitrary URL via their browser. If that's not sufficient enough, you can always check the [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) where you can upload file data by creating or updating a File resource.