# How do I call Google Drive API v3 in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I try to find ways to read and write Google drive described in.
[Codenameone Connect to Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109278/codenameone-connect-to-google-drive)

But The Google Sign-In JavaScript platform library for Web is deprecated, and unavailable for download after March 31, 2023.

I also find the document but need to call Google Identity Services authorization API. I think I can't use this API in cn1.
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

Any advices for Google Drive read/write for my cn1 app user?

Comment: You linked to the web version. For a native app I'm assuming you will need [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started) and the respective [ios version](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start). Right now we don't have those. I'm guessing this would be doable as a cn1lib as we did for the [sign-in with Apple](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-applesignin) which you can use as a reference.